# altering my connect code to protect from SQL injection

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I was wondering if someone would be able to help me alter my connect code & queries so that it helps to protect me from SQL injection?

Any advice would be amazing

I have the below code in a dbconfig.php file:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "fnjfi8378f3hrn39fb3";
$dbname = "crm4";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

and the below on a web page running a query:

```
<?php


                $sql = "SELECT format(count(id),0) as id3 FROM Orders 
                INNER JOIN membership_userrecords ON Orders.id = membership_userrecords.pkValue
where Year = 2017 AND membership_userrecords.memberID = '$memberid' AND membership_userrecords.tableName='Orders'


";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result2->fetch_assoc();
echo $row["id3"];


?>
```

Comment: The connection seems fine, but you should change your query to use prepared statement with bind variables http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Are you getting the $memberid value from user-end; if yes use mysqli_real_escape_string()

Comment: Don't escape it - just prepare and bind